# In Excel, is it possible to create a graph for every category of data, from the same table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I'm using Excel and PowerPivot to import some data from database, wich creates a single table (Sales). Let's say my table Sales has 3 columns: Sales, Month, and Category. There are 4 categories. I want to create a graph for every category, and be able to filter them at once by month. Is it possible? Or do I need to create four different tables first, then create the graphs, etc.?

What I have:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: The normal graphing function can't do that but starting with Excel 2010, there's a feature called "sparklines".  It lets you stick simple mini-graphs where you want.  You could assemble the kind of thing you show using that.  Check out https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/excel-2010-sparklines-review-mini-charts-win-loss/.

Answer (score 1):

I would create the 4 Pivot Charts, each filtered to a particular category.

Then I would add a Slicer for the Month.  Select the Slicer and choose Report Connections (right-click or use the Slicer Tools ribbon). Check all 4 Pivot Charts.